# How can i compress when I create SQL backup file in a folder?

Tags: windows, backup, script, compression, sql-server

I use [`SQL Server Express`](http://www.microsoft.com/turkiye/sql/editions/express/default.mspx) and I create backup files for all databases every day using `Time Scheduling` script. One script Like that;

```
BACKUP DATABASE [Jira]
TO DISK = N'C:\Backup\Jira.bak'
WITH COMPRESSION,INIT
GO
```

And they made 3 `.bak` (backup) file in my `C:/backup` folder.

What I want is, when I create these `.bak` files, I want also compress them automaticly (Maybe using with `Winrar`, `Winzip`, `7zip` or `SQL Express Server` properties)

Is there any way that I can do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could alternatively use a batch script.

Here is an example one, it will need to be tweaked a little.
In this example I use 7zip, which is free.

```
@echo off

CLS

SET backuptime=%DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~7,2%-%DATE:~4,2%-%TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%

echo %backuptime%

echo Running dump ...

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE" -S 
(local)\SQLExpress -i D:\dbbackups\bk_%SQLExpressBackups.sql

echo Zipping ...

"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "D:\dbbackups\zipped\bk_%backuptime%.zip" "D:\dbbackups\bk_%SQLExpressBackups.sql"

echo Deleting the SQL file ...

del "D:\dbbackups\bk_%SQLExpressBackups.sql"

echo Done!
```

Or if you want to just zip up the back up foler, after the back up is done you could do the following:

```
@echo off

CLS

SET backuptime=%DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~7,2%-%DATE:~4,2%-%TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%

echo %backuptime%

echo Zipping ...

"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "C:\dbbackups\zipped\bk_%backuptime%.zip" "C:\Backup\Jira.bak"

echo Done!
```

Save this as sqlbackup.bat and schedule it to be run everyday.

Comment: I already create .bak files mine C:/backup folder. Just i want to zipped that files. As I understand, I just only create new notepad, write `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "D:\dbbackups\zipped\bk_%backuptime%.zip" "D:\dbbackups\bk_%SQLExpressBackups.sql"`, Than save as .bat, and run everday in task scheduler. Right ?

Comment: Yep. If you schedule it for after the backup is scheduled then it should run and zip up your files.   I'll amend the question.  The zip file will be named with a timestamp.

Comment: You will need to make sure that the backup does not overlap with the zip, that's why the first approach is probably better.

Comment: How can i put this .bat file into Time Scheduler ?

Comment: [Check this out](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000785.htm). It details how to run a batch at a specific time.

Comment: What is `SET backuptime=%DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~7,2%-%DATE:~4,2%-%TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%` for ?

Comment: It puts a timestamp on the zip file something like bk_10-07-1978.zip so that the zip file is not constantly overwritten.

Comment: Great! It perfectly works.

Comment: Good to hear. ...